# mocking ioredis get , set in jest (library used nodejs)

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, ts-jest, ioredis

How to mock the ioredis get set in jest testcase .

my api is as given below:-

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redisClient = new Redis();

router.get('/qms', async (req, res, next) => {
      let data = await redisClient.get('qms');
      console.log(data)
}
})
```

my jest testcase is as given below:-

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
let redisClient = new Redis();
jest.mock('ioredis', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() => redisClient), // Mock the creation of a new Redis client
  };
});

describe('QMS get API tests', () => {

  it('should return QMS data if available', async () => {
    
    // await redisClient.set('qms', JSON.stringify({ date: new Date(), description: 'Server token description' }));
    // await redisClient.get('qms');

    redisClient.get.mockResolvedValue(JSON.stringify({ date: new Date(), description: 'Server token description' }));

    const response = await request(app).get('/api/automation/qms');

    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    // expect(response.body).toEqual({  status: false, description: 'Not started yet' });
  });

});
```

but when i have written above testcase , it is not mocking in the api properly in await redisClient.get('qms');
i am also doing console.log(data) , but it is giving undefined .

please suggest the updated code for testcase

i have also tried ioredis-mock , but it is working in testcase only but in api it is logging undefined only .